# Modify split form datasheet view format

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, subform, expandable

I have a split form with a subform. Each time the form is loaded, the subform data expands automatically.

Is there a way to automatically collapse the datasheet view of the subform when the form loads?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use VBA to automatically collapse the subform when it is loaded:

```
Dim strExpand As String

With Forms("Purchase Orders")

strExpand = InputBox("Expand subdatasheets? Y/N")

Select Case strExpand
    Case "Y"
        .SubdatasheetExpanded = True
    Case "N"
        .SubdatasheetExpanded = False
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Can't determine subdatasheet expansion state."
End Select

End With
```

Comment: to make it easier and to force the user to say Yes or No, you should use `strExpand =MsgBox ("Expand subdatasheets?", vbYesNo)` rather